# add to input form section

Tags: jquery

I am running a script that allows me to generate form fields. It predetermines the form structure and it's encrypted so I cannot change that.

It outputs like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="">
```

In the script I can choose the name and value.

I want to use jquery to make it look like this

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" required>
```

I want to insert the word "required" at the end (withing the `<input   >`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply,

```
<input id ='name' type="text" name="name" value="">

$('#name').prop('required', true);
```

### Edit as per comment

If you want to do it for single input select using name selector / id selector ,

```
$('input[name=name]').prop('required', true);
```

To do for all input field just use,

```
$('input').each(function() {
    $(this).prop('required', true)
});
```

### [Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zZr4M/)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but the script does not generate an id for the input field so there is not id.

Can it be done by linking for all input fields and then add the required? I will now how to set which input field to place it in I just need to know how to insert it based on the face that it is an input field.

Thank you

Comment: Thank you so much. Was able to use your first code suggestion by using addClass to add a class to the input section and using .name instead of #name and it inserted required="" that's close but I just want it to insert the word required not required="".

Comment: @thepcman required would do same as required="" do.Try using this..if you face any issue then let me know

Comment: Thank you so much, this is really a great place to learn. I really appreciate your help. I will try all you suggested when I get a some time.

Thank you

Comment: Your method woks great but as stated before, all I needed was the word required inserted so it looks like this 
<input name="Name" type="text" required>

I am using this here to validate 
http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Now it looks like this 
<input name="Name" type="text" required="">

But I thank so much becasue what you gave me works but it's not as clean as having just required .

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which language you're inserting input in with, but I'll write the code in Javascript.

```
var input = '<input type="text" name="name" value="">'; //the field you're given

var newInput = input.substring(0, input.length - 1) + ' required/>';
```

I added the slash to the end of the input as that is standard syntax.

Comment: I am running jqeury codes already so I would rather stick with just JQ. I will keep this in mind for other projects though.

Thank you very much